# How to import laravel project from windows to linux?

Tags: linux, laravel, laravel-4

I've a created a Laravel project on my Windows environment which is worrking fine.. Now I have to move this project to Linux environment. I've tried the following methods but failed.

**Method1**:. Created a new project on Linux using `composer create-project laravel/laravel` and replaced app directory with local instance app directory

**Method2**. Moved entire project from windows to Linux (through FTP).

In both the above methods I failed to access my URLs. I'm sure that everything installed correctly on Linux machine.

When I  access my the project on Linux `/public` I could see the success screen *You've arrived*.

[image]

But when I access my view pages like `public/users/login`. I'm getting **Page Not Found** error. The same path working fine under my windows.

What could be the wrong. I'm newbie in Laravel. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: After replacing app directory in linux try using `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @ArunKumar tried but nothing happened when I execute the command I could see 'Generating autoload files' but same 404 error. btw I executed the command at `/var/ww/html/myproject`. Is that right?

Comment: Does `/public/index.php/users/login` work?

Comment: @lukasgeiter wow!! awesome yes yes it's working. So do I need to do any changes. Please add this as answer so that I will accpet

Comment: Make sure you have [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess) in your `public/.htaccess` file

Comment: @lukasgeiter Yes, that is already exists in my .htaccess file.

Comment: Maybe you need to enable .htaccess. [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file) should help

Comment: Yes, might be. Thanks @lukasgeiter you saved my day. Thanks a lot. When you've time please make this as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the route works with `/public/index.php/users/login` (and it *does*, see comments) it means something with the .htaccess URL rewriting isn't working properly.
These are the things you can check:

1. `public/.htaccess` should be [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess)
2. .htaccess has to be enabled on the server [Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file)